# Access Rest API from Google Apps Script

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, google-apps-script

I am using Google Scripts to connect to Salesforce REST API. I am using the library `1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF`

```
function getService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
 return OAuth2.createService('salesforce')
      // Set the endpoint URLs
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://flolive.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize')
      .setTokenUrl('https://flolive.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token')

      // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
     //   .setCache(CacheService.getDocumentCache())
      // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
    
     // .setScope('r_organization_social,r_basicprofile,r_liteprofile,rw_organization_admin,r_ads_reporting,r_ads')

      // Below are salesforce-specific OAuth2 parameters.

        .setParam('response_type', 'code')
      
      // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
      // but not desirable in a production application.
      //.setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var salesforceService = getService();
  var isAuthorized = salesforceService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
}

function logOut() {
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties();

  var service=getService();
    service.reset();

  
}
```

The thing is that it does work, for a little bit of time and then I get the message **Error: Access not granted or expired.
Service_.getAccessToken @ Service.gs:466**

Now this code saves the initial access token. I've also tried taking the access token directly from the *Settings > Apps Manager > Initial Access Token for Dynamic Client Registration*

And when I hardcode that it says **INVALID_SESSION_ID Session expired or invalid**

The thing is that this works periodically but not consistently. What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: The access token expires, you need to generate a new one. Example: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/Salesforce.gs

Comment: @identigral how do I increase the expiration date on the access tokens, because this happens often and then I get the error on this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71728798/api-suddently-started-throwing-error-access-not-granted-or-expired-service-ge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71728798/api-suddently-started-throwing-error-access-not-granted-or-expired-service-ge)

Comment: That is controlled by a session policy on Salesforce side. There are multiple policy levels. The one you want is on the connected app that corresponds to your client id. See doc: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_manage_session_policies.htm&type=5 . There's no option to keep the token unexpired forever, you'll need to use a refresh token as Google's example linked above shows.

Comment: @identigral that seems to be working for now.

Comment: @identigral, present an answer and I'll mark it as the answer. This seems to be working now